# how to find hours of the day between two date times excel or MS access

Tags: excel, datetime, ms-access

I have a report where im supposed to collect data for different hour blocks of the day between issued date time and completed date time. e.g IssueDateTime = 12/19/2016 10:00 AM and CompletedDateTime = 12/19/2016 3:00 PM i would expect the formula to return 10:00 AM, 11:00 AM, 12:00 PM, 1:00 PM, 2:00 PM, 3:00 PM. dont know if this is even possible but any insight will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you expecting the time or time difference? I guess, this is what you need, the formula `TIME(HOUR(C2), MINUTE(C2), SECOND(C2))`. See this - http://excelsemipro.com/2012/10/extract-time-from-a-date-time-number-in-excel/

Comment: im expecting both in this cases since the difference is between the example is 5 hour i need the out put to be 1 hour intervals from each other until it reached the completed date time

Comment: thanks for the link but im affraid it does not provide me with what im looking for

Comment: Are you working in Access or Excel? Also, you are expecting output of several hour blocks for two inputs. where do you expect the several hour numbers to be output to? (I think you'll most likely need some sort of VBA routine for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to do the same thing with VBA / Access:

```
cdate(DatePart("h",Now())& ":00")
```

This will return 1:00:00 PM for current time here (1:12 PM)

To get just hour itself, use:

```
DatePart("h",Now())
```

Here is simple function that returns all hour blocks between 2 different times:

```
Public Function ShowHourBlocks(StartTime As Date, EndTime As Date) As String

    Dim StartBlock As Date
    Dim EndBlock As Date
    Dim Answer As String

    StartBlock = CDate(DatePart("h", StartTime) & ":00")
    EndBlock = CDate(DatePart("h", EndTime) & ":00")

    Do While StartBlock <= EndBlock

        Answer = Answer + Format(StartBlock, "h:mm AMPM") & " "
        StartBlock = DateAdd("h", 1, StartBlock)

    Loop


    ShowHourBlocks = Answer

End Function
```

Here is what returns when you run it in immediate window:

```
?ShowHourBlocks(now(), DateAdd("h",4,Now()))
1:00 PM 2:00 PM 3:00 PM 4:00 PM 5:00 PM
```

Comment: this solution is works only if you are using one date time field not two

Comment: what do you mean one date time? you place start and end time between brackets when calling function with comma between , just like I did in example (start time  = now() and end time = now + 5 hours).

Comment: this works with Now function, however im having trouble when i add the actual date time fields. could assist with this ?

Comment: I apologize, i managed to get to work this solution work perfectly. Thank you very much Veil i have researching for  like this for days. you are a life saver

Comment: You should never - no exceptions - use string handling for date and time. In this case, _TimeSerial_ would be the choice: `StartBlock = TimeSerial(Hour(StartTime), 0, 0)`.

Answer (score 0):

This formula will return an array of the hours:

```
=TEXT(ROW(INDIRECT(HOUR(IssueDateTime) & ":" & HOUR(CompletedDateTime)))/24,"hh:mm AM/PM")
```

For your example, the formula returns:

```
{"10:00 AM";"11:00 AM";"12:00 PM";"01:00 PM";"02:00 PM";"03:00 PM"}
```

but when entered into a single cell, you will only see the first element.

You can display the full result either by entering the formula as an array, or by using the `INDEX` function.

If you are not familiar with arrays in Excel, I suggest reading the HELP topics in Excel and on MSDN, and also see [Chip Pearsons Introduction to Array Formulas](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/ArrayFormulas.aspx)

Here is an example.  The array formula was entered B4:B17, and Conditional Formatting was used to make the `#N/A` results appear blank.

[image]

Comment: I tried using this formula as an Array and just a regular formula but i keep getting the #Value! error, any ideas why this might be happening ?

Comment: @user3667159 Not really.  Obviously you are doing something unexpected, but since you don't indicate what you are doing, your question is too broad to be answered in this format.  The formula works here.  I'll edit my answer to show.